# Как правильно передать переменную в mixin (SCSS)?

Tags: sass, scss

Пробую реализовать некий `mixin`, который будет выполнять всю шаблонную работу, а мне останется лишь передавать в него нужные конструкции в виде классов и их свойств.

Что должно получиться на выходе:

```
.test-1 {
  color: red;
}

.test-2 {
  color: red;
}

.test-3 {
  color: red;
}
```

Как вижу это я:

```
@mixin get() {
  @for $i from 1 through 3 {
    @content;
  }
}

@include get() {
  .test-#{$i} {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

В моем варианте компилятор ругается, мол переменной `$i` еще не существует, а я ее пытаюсь передать в `mixin`.

Ошибку я понимаю, но как тогда решить задачу с присвоением `$i` в конце названия класса `test` внутри тела `mixin get`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решена следующим образом:

```
@mixin get($class-name) {
  @for $i from 1 through 3 {
    .#{$class-name}-#{$i} {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

@include get('test') {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @mixin border-radius($radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
     -moz-border-radius: $radius;
      -ms-border-radius: $radius;
          border-radius: $radius;
}

.box { @include border-radius(10px); }
```

Вот пример. Что сложного?

Comment: Ему еще нужно изменить имя класса автоматом.

Comment: Совершенно ничего сложного, кроме того, что Ваш ответ не относиться к моему вопросу...

Answer (score 0):

Немного не так это делается. Покажу на примере.

```
$text_px: 8, 9, 10;

@each $var in $text_px {
    .t#{$var}px {
        font-size: #{$var}px;
    }
}
```

На выходе будет:

```
.t8px {font-size: 8px;}
.t9px {font-size: 9px;}
.t10px {font-size: 10px;}
```

То есть генерация происходит в цикле `@each`, где последовательно преребираются все значения из переменной.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, @each перебирает массив, а не переменную. Ваш ответ понятен, но он не решает мою задачу... Сможете показать Ваше решение в рамках моей задачи?

Comment: Как вариант в $text_px вы задаёте нужные значения (1,2,3 и т.п.). Если вам нужно что-то особое, то следует учтонить задачу.